# Eclipse color theme import doesn't work properly?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am an Eclipse newbie.

I have downloaded an .epf file from here: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

and imported it like this: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use

the result is not exactly what one would expect:
[image]
(note that some characters, like '=' or ')', are black. Also highlighted text is unreadable.

I have tried other themes, and the result was similar.

Why doesn't it work? What do I do wrong? Does it work for you, Eclipse users? How to restore defaults?

My eclipse version is 3.8.1. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.